# How to find the Integral Definition of Triangular Numbers.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

The triangular numbers $T_k$ namely :

$$1,3,6,10,15,21 ...$$

are the result of the sum :

$$ T_k =\sum_{n=1}^K n$$

and given by :

$$T_k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2} $$

They have a generating function :

$$ \frac{x}{(1-x)^3} $$

So my question is : how can i use the generating function of the triangular numbers to come up with an integral definition for them?

That is :

$$ T_k = \int_a^b f(k)  \,dx $$

Are there general procedures that should be done if this were to be a different example? For finding an integral definition of a sequence using its generating function?

Thank you kindly for your help and time.

Comment: Do you need to use the generating function?  Given the algebriac $T_k=\frac 12k^2 + \frac 12k$ it is natural to say $T_k=\int_0^k(x+\frac 12)dx$

Comment: @RossMillikan the nature of the question is that i am studying a sequence that is quite complex and i have been unable to find an integral definition for it , but i was able to find its generating function and was hoping there would be a connection between the generating function and an Integral Definition for the sequence.